# Unable to link my 200+ rep Programmers.SE account to my Stack Overflow Careers Profile

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, jobs

When editing [my career profile](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/users/info/119009) I am unable to add a link to my [Programmers.SE account](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/31260/gnat).

For this account, I passed 200+ rep limit about a week ago.

This looks like a bug because I expect to be able to do that.

- Screen shot below
  Couple accounts are there
  *Programmers* not listed - that's the issue:

[image]

---

- In case if that matters, here is my past request about a similar issue with other account:
  [career profile: unable to link my 200+ rep account...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100372/career-profile-unable-to-link-my-200-rep-account-though-answers-link-fine)
  (above was for SO account, was fixed about a month ago)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed.  SiteUsers only updates once per day, but you had a network identifier change that we hadn't picked up yet.  All is in order now.