# My "not an answer" flag is gone and not showing in my history

Tags: support, flags, declined-flags, not-an-answer

Some time ago I flagged [this as not-an-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185937/overriding-the-java-equals-method-quirk/185946#185946).

For a while, link to this flagged answer has been visible in my flagging history (flag was declined in case if that matters). As far as I remember it also has been counted among my other declined flags.

Recently I discovered that link to answer is not present in my flagging history anymore. Nor does it impact the number of declined flags anymore.

Some other flagged answers that disappeared in a similar fashion are listed in this question:

- [Was it a mistake to flag these answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109383/was-it-a-mistake-to-flag-these-answers)

As far as I can tell, [diamond moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75189/who-are-the-diamond-moderators-and-what-is-their-role) can't see these flags, either: "looking through your flagging history and I don't see flags that were declined on these questions. I also don't see anything on the individual flag histories for each post" - comments from *Bill the Lizard♦* in this question:

- [Serial flag decliner](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109912/serial-flag-decliner)

What happened to my flagging history?

Comment: Forgetting context of the question for a moment, what the hell is a NAN? In fact, in context of the question what the hell is it? "Not a number" aside...

Comment: Maybe it should be NAA ("not an answer"), which is what gnat seems talking of.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment _NAN_ is the thing that is gone. I mean, links to particular answers flagged as _N-ot an AN-swer_ are gone from my flagging history. Links to answers I thought about as described in the flag - "should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely flags were deleted by someone of Stack Exchange team. I can not think of any other reason for why flags disappeared from my flagging history even for diamond moderators.

Most likely, there was [some sort of cleanup](https://meta.superuser.com/a/3356/97481) going on there.

Comment: We don't delete flags like this...I honestly see no history of a flag on that question at all, or how it would disappear (we don't hard delete flags).

Comment: @NickCraver I see thanks. Can you think of any other reason for why flags would disappear other than _hard deletion_? As you may see from the [prior question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109383/was-it-a-mistake-to-flag-these-answers) I mentioned, few mods have seen my flags there indeed

Comment: Other than your account being merged (I don't see that ever happening to you), no...the records should be in the database.  Soft delete refers to we have a DeletionDate column and it's populated...hard delete is the database row is literally gone, that seems to be the case here, if it's a bug I'm not seeing it....but such is the nature of bugs so...  We have some changes to how flags are stored coming up (they're in a few different locations for posts/comments currently, we want to clean that up), if there is a bug it'll disappear with that changeover.

Comment: @NickCraver I see - interesting. I recall one account merge for sure: [P.SE+SO in August](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103662/unable-to-link-my-200-rep-programmers-se-account-to-my-stack-overflow-careers-p) - seems there were none except for this one. As for _row deletion_ well without knowing if you have audit records for DB changes or archived snapshots for past dates it is hard to tell what happened. If there is sort of "wayback machine", it would be possible eg to check for row deletions done between Oct 15 and 22

Comment: @NickCraver _"We don't delete flags like this"_ well as far as I can tell at SU it happened once that **flag decisions were reversed** somehow. I updated an answer with the [link to SU example](http://meta.superuser.com/a/3356/97481)