# Is the "helpful flags" count reset periodically?

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags

I had flagged a few things, was up to 14 (i think) of helpful flags out of just a few more than that.  I logged in today and all my flags were gone except for one. Do these get reset every now and then?  Is it a bug that they went away?

[image: Missing Flags]

and the flagging summary

[image: flagging summary]

Comment: What is displayed when you click on the `1` link next to `helpful flags` in your profile?

Comment: Bizarre... deleted posts certainly still count, so it wouldn't be due to something like that.  I've never seen or heard of it resetting for any reason.

Comment: Your rep and consecutive days, etc. were still the same?

Comment: yes, everything else on my account is still the same.   The only difference in my account is I opened a beta account using the same login on workplace.se

Comment: Check the `my logins` link on your profile pages to make sure they all match, though it's not likely to be the case since you have your rep and all of that.  Also, it looks like you just got the Citizen Patrol badge for the first time today (or in the last day or so), and that's only awarded once.

Comment: All is the same.  I was awarded that badrge s while ago

Comment: It must have been less than 2 days ago, because that's when you got the badge before Citizen Patrol (click on the teacher badge in your profile to see that it was 2d ago)

Comment: See what one of those friendly neighborhood web slingers (the devs) have to say, as they can probe your actual account, I'm just using the publicly available data.

Comment: Did you recently merge an account with this one? Merging accounts automatically clears flag history for both accounts.

Comment: @TwilightSparkle: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110016/my-not-an-answer-flag-is-gone-and-not-showing-in-my-history#comment302765_115509 - That's the first one I found.

Comment: Ugh. Can you please crop that image?

Comment: @AlEverett I was trying to show with that image that it was all that was there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You had two accounts. Your newer account ([SO user 1144482](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144482) <sup>[[cache screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdH6D.png)]</sup>, [SE account 1166288](https://stackexchange.com/users/1166288)) had practically all of your reputation and presumably flags. That newer account was recently merged into your older account ([SO user 1135092](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1135092) <sup>[[cache screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edaNv.png)]</sup>, [SE account 1153988](https://stackexchange.com/users/1153988)).

The [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) is that when accounts are merged, flags attributed to the user id of the removed account are not re-attributed to the preserved account; they're practically lost. Flags on the preserved account are not lost (or at least they weren't when I merged an account into mine six months ago).

If you didn't intend to merge accounts, you may have done so accidentally by adding a login associated with your older account to your newer account.

Answer (score 7):

No, it's not reset...it was just not handled in merges.  Previously this was a number called "flag weight" which was calculated as a running total algorithmically with each delta applied, but not something we could regenerate due to not storing enough data on comment votes.

But since this changed, there's no reason we can't start merging it properly...starting with the next build future merges will handle/merge flag counts properly.

Comment: are old flags just gone then? or will they come back with the next build?

Comment: @bretterer - they are gone, hard deleted from the database (always been this way), I can only sanely fix this for future merges.  The alternative is restoring terabytes of daily backups to get total counts...and even then we'd miss anything created and deleted in that day, it's just not worth the many days it'd take to do that compared to what else we could be adding/fixing on the sites.

Comment: Not really a problem.. just curious about it more than anything.