# How to positively steer a new user

Tags: discussion, new-users, low-quality-posts

As I was making my way through a couple questions, I ran into an answer from a new user that was extremely low-quality.  So, being semi-diligent, I looked to see if the user was consistently answering with low-quality answers, and sure enough, every answer that they had provided was mildly on-topic at best, and terse or nearly link-only.  Further, being a user for only 15 minutes, they had answered 5 questions in this manner.

[This is the user in question](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3375389/karuption).

Downvoting every answer and putting the same, canned, "Welcome to SO, `insert specific helpful request`. Please read the FAQ about how to better format answers," would be kind of cruel and unfair (since it was every question that had the issue), and the answers aren't so bad that flagging for moderator attention on a per-question basis is really viable.  If it were isolated answers (1 bad one in every few), this would work, but from the 5 answers given, it looks more chronic.

Adding a way to flag a new user for moderator attention (gentle encouragement, etc.) would be extremely helpful in these cases, where they are shotgun answering questions, so the issue can be corrected and so that they can quickly become a contributing member of the SE/SO family.

If adding some way of re-mediating a user that isn't used to the SO Q&A style isn't possible, what are the current mechanisms that are in place to correct this kind of behaviour?

Comment: This user seems like he/she has good intentions.  Leaving specific comments on a couple of the answers should do the trick.  He/she may be coming from a more traditional forum where answering with hints and tricks is acceptable.

Comment: @jonsca That's my normal approach, but since there were so many "good intention" posts in such a short amount of time, it seems like it's a bit of a special case (not sure how often that happens with new users).

Comment: You should call them out on meta 3 hours after they create their account; that way we can be sure they feel persecuted^Wwelcome.

Comment: @Wooble He was the example, I've not ran into the issue before, so I wasn't sure on the best approach to handle it.  I also attempted to handle it with some tact, it wasn't a name and shame.

Comment: When I want to positively steer a new user, I always make sure I have a good set of pliers.

Comment: "Downvoting every answer... would be kind of cruel and unfair": no, downvoting bad answers is not "unfair". It is entirely fair to down vote bad answers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As one answer on [this related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167452/162102) says, *lead by example and treat them with respect*.  In this case, you can:

- Leave specific comments explaining how posts could be improved.  I tend toward language like "you could improve this answer by [edit]ing in a source for X".
- If you don't understand an argument being made, ask a question in a comment.  Cast it as "could you explain X?" or "I'm having trouble understanding X; can you fill that out more?".  Use "I" language, not "you" language.  (Don't say "you're not making sense" or the like, even if it's true.)
- Leave comments pointing to relevant help-center pages or meta posts. *Assume that the user wants to be a good citizen but just doesn't understand how we work yet.*  I tend to say something like "(Site) is a little different from many others.  We're not a forum; we focus on questions and answers, not discussion. If you haven't already, please check out [about] for more about how we work."  (Of course, customize this for the specific situation.)
- If you can, edit some posts to illustrate what we're looking for, and be sure to leave both a meaningful edit note and a comment.  The comment may seem redundant, but many new users don't know that they can see the diff and edit note by clicking on the "edited" link.  In the comment, say something like "I've edited this to (whatever you did, broadly, like "fix formatting" or "add a link to your source").  You can see the edit details by clicking on...".  In other words, use your edit to *teach*, not just to fix the problem.
- If the user gets up to 20 rep but still seems to be struggling, invite him into chat.

Only if the problem is particularly egregious or prolonged should you use flags to appeal to moderators.  If nobody has done any of the things I've listed above then they really can't do anything special anyway -- they can leave comments or make edits, but *so can you* so why escalate?  SE communities work best when the whole community works together to improve posts and guide newcomers.

Comment: Honestly, this question was as much for myself as for the user.  I'm trying to be more active on the helping front and I've always kinda just went with leave a comment, so knowing there are some other ways to encourage the user down the right path that doesn't need mod intervention is nice.

Answer (score -3):

Just choose one of the posts and use a custom mod flag to explain that all/most of this user's posts have the same problems.  The moderator can then look through all of them and handle them appropriately.

This workaround is sufficient; there's really no compelling need to have a special flag for multiple posts when you can just say that it is in the flag reason.

Comment: In this case, I don't think it really requires a mod's intervention.  The user seems misguided rather than that they are breaking any particular rules.

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian Rather than going through all 5 of a users posts flagging all of them for the same thing, you can simply flag one and indicate that they all have the same problem.  The OP stated that he's looking for some special UI to do this; that there should be some special feature for flagging a user, rather than a post.  The point is that there's no need.  Now if, using the specific example that this person gave, that's not needed, that's different from addressing the general question itself.