# Sudden increase in off-topic posts on MSE

Tags: support, off-topic, terms-of-service

It seems that the *Updated Terms of Service* message linking to the [MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277369/165773) discussing it had a undesired side effect: there is a huge increase in off-topic (mostly programming) questions. (Not to speak about the hundreds of drive-by upvotes on that posts and its answers...)

While I think the message itself is useful, wouldn't it be better to link to a blog post or something next time?

Also, can we warn users coming here now this is not the place to ask programming questions? Maybe using a custom notice for a few days?

Comment: Already proposed in chat: http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4829949#4829949

Comment: Oh, yes, a flashing banner. You have my vote for that :)

Comment: I would say: do nothing. It is a great way to boost my close vote review stats and spend some delete votes here ...

Comment: Another option is to temporarily 'protect' the entire site, i.e. you would need to have 10 reputation *earned on this site* in order to post a question.

Comment: Nice suggestion @Glorfindel

Comment: You're assuming people actually read such alert / instructional messages. If that were true then there wouldn't be any off-topic posts here anyway - the 'Ask a question' page already prompts "What's your bug, feature request, or meta-discussion topic? Be specific." and has bold text asking "**Is your question about the Stack Exchange engine that powers the Stack Exchange**. Those already get ignored. Would more alerts make a difference?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ways to give users some specific education about question quality and topicality](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277607/ways-to-give-users-some-specific-education-about-question-quality-and-topicality)

Comment: @gnat Thanks for that other post. This is not just about that, also about the decision to use a meta post as the message link, which was quite confusing to me too. (Also, I am asking for a more temporary fix to the current intake)

Comment: @rene: same here, but I'm almost running out of flags ...

Comment: @Glorfindel same here, which is, for MSE, a new experience for me ...

Comment: @Pat in case you missed it, see Tim Post answer below - we just got a boost, you have more close votes now. :)

Comment: Just gave everyone more votes until this ramps down.

Comment: Almost wrote it as "If you ask a programming question, Patrick is probably going to eat you" which I think would have been _great_, but we'll have to settle with what I ended up saving.

Comment: Am I receiving [this warning](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uEQjX.png) due to this?

Comment: @Arulkumar Yes, that message is there because folks are going to stack overflow, noticing the TOS update message in their inbox, coming here and reading the discussion then forgetting they're on another site when they go to do what they originally wanted to do, which was ask a question. It's just reminding them to go back to Stack Overflow, and it's shown to everyone for the next two days.

Comment: @TimPost : Oh, Okay. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @PatrickHofman retracted dupe vote only because I got curious how they will handle similar issue when it bites them where it hurts. :) Programmers experience this pain (and complains about it at meta) for about two years now, since burn down of SO close queue in Spring 2014. 20% questions over there are asked by users blocked at Stack Overflow, go figure

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Update (April 21, 2016)**

Note - we raised the minimum reputation here on MSE to ask to 2 from 1 (which should be just enough friction to slow this down) for the next few days.

**Update (April 20, 2016)**

Y'all now have 50 close votes a day while this persists, I plan to put it back to 24 before the end of the week. It's picking up even more.

I have also added a system message that will last for two days, since I saw two *more* come in back-to-back in the time it took me to write my last update. It's a bad experience for them, and us.

Still stand behind my original answer - this needs more fixing after we take the band-aid off on Friday.

---

It's a question of audience. If you *really* want to make sure most people that have an investment (and, likely, an opinion) about changes like this have an opportunity to see discussions and opine if they choose - this is the best place to make that happen. While some of you do read the blog, the audience there has shifted more to folks that are more passively keeping tabs on what we're doing.

Since all of the details of what we did and why we did it were explained (some a few times over) *here*, it just made the most sense to set the link here, rather than duplicating everything we wrote, in addition to conveying the sentiments of folks that took part in the conversation.

While the problem did spike when we shipped the inbox notification, it's been steadily on the rise for the last few months independently. About half of the people that ask programming questions here *are* genuinely lost, the other half are blocked on Stack Overflow. It's not a *huge* problem, it's certainly dealt with easily, but I've also been finding it more than marginally annoying as MSE/MSO are my morning newspapers that I read with coffee.

I think treating this *temporary* situation would mean not putting a little more thought into how we could be more specific, but not off-putting about what we do on meta sites as part of the new user experience on meta sites. Actually, I've been thinking about ways meta could be better for meta stuff in general lately.

I'm going to put some more thought into it and make it an actual initiative I track on my calendar, I'd rather fix (or really diminish) the problem at the more fundamental level.

Comment: Can you please take a look [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278588/redirecting-to-different-state-while-refreshing-a-state#comment902243_278588) with your CM powers? If this is true, well, it's really bad for us.

Comment: FYI: we did see this [comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278588/redirecting-to-different-state-while-refreshing-a-state#comment902243_278588) but weren't able so far to confirm if that is a bug. And desperate as I was I tried to get hold of [this user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36744161/select-from-php#comment61069531_36744161) without success.

Comment: @rene I'm going to chase that down now, and see if there's anything to it.

Comment: I feel it could blink more.

Comment: It will blink, precisely once. It's actually mid-blink now and the single blink cycle will complete on Friday at around this time.

Comment: Nice message, can't it be displayed only to 1 rep users?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Nope, it's all or nothing. But it's way better than badly written programming questions, and you don't have to close system messages. Still leaving the extra votes on just in case.

Comment: Thanks, fair enough. More than I expected. :)

Comment: hope this incident will help you better understand how it feels like at Programmers when users blocked / warned at Stack Overflow dump their off-topic garbage over there (Programmers [meta-tag:hot-questions] at sidebar serve as a _permanent announcement_ - "hey here's yet another site to try your luck at")

Comment: I have to agree with @gnat.  We don't have a diamond with enough moxy on Programmers to do this, unfortunately, and SE doesn't have much interest in our off-topic woes.

Comment: Can you raise the number of flags a day as well? I don't have any left for today ...

Comment: @Glorfindel The banner along with doubling the close votes seems to have really dulled it down. I don't want to go changing _too_ many things temporarily, especially allocated flags, because that's a whole system where your flags increase over time based on your history of flagging and rep (there could be some unintended consequences in bumping it up for a couple of days)

Comment: **[typical look of Programmers front page...](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pWwhs.png)** oh wait that's MSE today!

Comment: How long is this restriction going to last?  I referred a user on SO to here in the hopes they could ask their question on what SE site to ask their question.  Since the user is new they only have 1 rep here and cannot just ask a question.  I get you want to keep the site clean but placing a barrier to ask IMHO is a little heavy handed.

Comment: Tim, over two weeks have passed since the rep limit to post here was raised to 2 - wouldn't it be interesting to see what happens if we recover it back to normal value?

Comment: To be fair, for a user new to SE who probably doesn't even know there _is_ such a thing as "meta" that looks almost exactly the same and has an "Ask Question" button but is not the same at all .... this is extremely confusing. I don't blame them for this at all.

Comment: Hello Tim. Why do I have 50 CVs on MSE? I suppose 24 is the correct number.

Comment: Hello again, Tim. When was the 24 CV restored? I'm just curious.

Comment: @iBugsaysReinstateMonica in 6-8

Answer (score 30):

To remedy these mishaps for now I went ahead and implemented the suggested banner that can be used as a user script:

```js
(function play() {
    "use strict";
    var banner = $('#banner'),
        ms = 600, // time in ms
        m = 'This is META. Go away with your programming questions!',
        states = ['#ff0000', '#00ff00', '#0000ff'],
        option = {"background-color":"", "color":"" };

    // fc = forecolor state
    // bc = backcolor state
    function loop(fc, bc) {
        option.color = states[fc];
        option["background-color"] = states[bc];
        banner.animate(
            option,
            ms,
            loop.bind(undefined, (fc + 1) % 3, (bc + 1) % 3)
        );
    }

    // init banner on first call
    if (banner.length === 0) {
        banner = $('<div id="banner"></div>');
        banner.append($('<h1 style="text-align:center"></h1>').text(m));
        $('#content').before(banner);
    }

    // loop the animation
    loop(0, 1);
})();
```

When implemented the user will get a friendly banner that will guide them to better places:

[image: meta banner]

Feel free to suggest better wording.

Comment: As much as we all love a good flashing banner (although it should probably marquee just for extra impact) I think this would just annoy far more people than it would benefit, to be honest. Don't penalise *everyone* just because some people don't pay enough attention.

Comment: @JonW you don't know how disappointed I was when I found out that `<blink>` and `<marquee>` are no longer supported. I used them a lot...

Comment: A "friendly" banner? I don't think that word means what you think it means.

Comment: @TRiGisTimothyRichardGreen pretty sure this was a joke.

Comment: you can adapt [this sketch that was made for similar "guest askers" at Programmers](http://i.stack.imgur.com/aXfX2.png)

Comment: @gnat if that *back* button would actually send users to Yahoo Answers! it would be perfect ;)

Comment: I feel like it could blink more.

Comment: @TimPost  In 6 to 8 weeks I'll make blink rate  user configurable

Comment: +1. It should show that banner here in MSE to all users with only one rep.