# 1 rep users can ask on Meta again

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, asking-questions

For some time, 1 rep users are banned from MSE. Today, a 1 rep user posted a coding question again (https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/280712/245360).

Has the ban been lifted or is it broken (again)?

Comment: [Create posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-posts) enable for 1 Reputation.

Comment: The ban is lifted, I left my default comment again and that post is now closed, we can delete vote it

Comment: @Arulkumar in general that is correct but we have had ... [incidents](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278562/sudden-increase-in-off-topic-posts-on-mse) so the reputation was adjusted to counter those off-topic posts.

Comment: Patrick keep it silent, I wanna spend some CV's and enjoy while doing it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The ban was lifted.

We have expired all the remaining unread "terms of services changed" inbox items, which was what caused a lot of people from Stack Overflow to drop here (and then ask their off-topic question here).

The thought behind that was that with that no longer alerting people, they will not come here after all.

Don't forget - we *always* had a number of people posting programming questions here, well before the terms of service inbox announcement. Hopefully, we are back to that "background level" of noise.

Comment: Indeed, appears to be back to 5-10 daily off topic programming questions here.

Comment: Yeah, but not the absolute deluge we had earlier :)

Comment: _"We have expired all the remaining unread "terms of services changed" inbox items, which was what caused a lot of people from Stack Overflow to drop here (and then ask their off-topic question here)."_ It's scary how unobservant and, well, _stupid_ so many people can be. :(

Comment: Nothing new there - there is a reason all the *important* buttons on Amazon are as big as they are... @LightnessRacesinOrbit