# Feature to detect if a question is about programming and thus off-topic

Tags: feature-request, new-users, off-topic

What if we had some sort of warning that users' questions seem off-topic, especially on MSE? It seems to me that a large majority of the blatantly off-topic questions here should be on Stack Overflow. It could work like this:

- It's got a list of keywords, sort of like Smoke Detector but for programming.

  - Maybe programming language names and terms, such as "Ruby" and "Python" and "if statement".
- It looks for if there are large codeblocks with a lot of what appears to be syntax.
- It disables if the user has more than 10 reputation or so on Meta.
- It runs when the "Post Your Question" button is pressed.

  - If the keyword condition or the codeblock condition is met and it is enabled, it displays some sort of thing like a box popping out of the posting button that has a message like "Are you sure this question is on-topic? This appears to be about programming. For questions about programming, go to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com)".

<sub>Ironic how it would trigger on this post if I had less reputation...</sub>

Comment: It's pretty common for people to be quoting, paraphrasing, or otherwise discussing the content of programming questions, so lots of *appropriate* meta questions have all of those things.

Comment: Programming is only one part of off-topic questions; we also get off-topic questions that run the gamut of SE sites.

Comment: @Servy this wouldn’t *stop* them from posting; it would just notify them that they’re on Meta, not SO and they could still post it if it were actually on-topic.

Comment: @fbueckery this could include those too, the description in the post is only about programming just because that’s a lot more narrow and it could trigger on many of the off-topic questions.

Comment: It's still a pretty wide net you'd be trying to cast.  Not sure how useful it would be to even make, with the potential issue of false positives.

Comment: I propose a [banner](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/278564/158100) ...

Comment: Simply roll a dice with 1s and 0s on it. If it lands on a 1, then mark the question off topic. It'll be right 50% of the time here.

Answer (score 8):

Like Servy says, many valid questions *about* code would cause false positives to such a detector and needlessly complicate posting them. And users come here with their [mathematics](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/327850/summation-of-1-infinite-times) and [general software/hardware problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/327812/295232) too.

I feel a modified [Ask Question Wizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/327257/295232) would be much more effective in discouraging users from posting blatantly off-topic questions, but some people are just too desperate for answers and will still post here.