# Add on-topic notice to the top part (logo row) for 1 rep users

Tags: feature-request, new-users, off-topic, scope, notification-bar

Whenever I see the blatantly off-topic questions on the site, I'm curious why the asker did this. This is probably due to a hidden from the asker's eyes on-topic notice.

What if we make the on-topic notice more visible to the asker by placing it on the logo row at the top of the page?

> [image]

This notice will be visible only for 1 rep users (maybe only on asking a new question page).

I think such type of notice will reduce the number of blatantly off-topic questions on any SE site.

Moreover turned out that the  notice about what is on-topic, e.g. here on MSE:

> Is your question about the Stack Exchange engine that powers the Stack Exchange network?

while asking the question doesn't exist at all. You need to switch to full site mode to make it visible.

Comment: Related: [People get lost and crash into meta - maybe we need roadblocks for their safety](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306329/people-get-lost-and-crash-into-meta-maybe-we-need-roadblocks-for-their-safety)

Comment: @Shadow please look at [tag:top-bar] description, it's a different thing.

Comment: True, so it's the notification bar, where the notifications go. (And adding such notification there should indeed be pretty simple for SE, technically.)