Is something in the Stack Exchange UI inadvertently wrongly leading people to MSE?
I've noticed recently that among the various posts here on meta.stackexchange.com that appear clearly intended for one or another main network site (and there seem to be a handful per day) that:

The OP usually is a new user with 1 rep
The OP is usually already also signed up on the right site for the question (or at least a reasonably good guess)

It seems to happen commonly enough that new users sign up for a network site specifically to ask a question, but then somehow end up posting it here instead of in the intended location. Typically these really are new accounts created the same day or almost as recently - so it doesn't make sense that this is Q-ban evasion from users whose questions have all been deleted.
What exactly is going on here? Does something about the Stack Exchange UI make it easy to post on MSE accidentally instead of on the main site where someone has just finished signing up?

Related https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306329/people-get-lost-and-crash-into-meta-maybe-we-need-roadblocks-for-their-safety

Also for extra fun, sometimes people don't realise per site metas exist, or better yet, think MSE means math.se :D

Related: Why do users often ask blatantly off-topic questions here on Meta?

I don't know about leading them here, but when I press the "Ask Question" button, I get a screen with a big box on the right hand size, which contains "Is your question about the Stack Exchange engine that powers the Stack Exchange network?" along with bunch of useful links providing further help. If that's not enough to stop what they're doing... then let them hit the wall and learn the hard way. We can't personally pamper every single user on a site with millions of accounts.

@DanMašek The right-hand column of any given webpage (that has one) might as well be invisible to anyone who doesn't already have a specific reason to look there.

There are 3 boxes on that page. If that's too much... who are we trying to cater to? Then make it a wizard, with first page asking "Is you question....". Big "NO", tiny little "Yes" tucked somewhere away. And I bet people will still post nonsense here. :/

The problem isn't the number of boxes. The problem is the physical layout.

It is missing a helpful banner: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/278564

Whenever it happens, why not simply ask the user how they ended up here? It happens frequently enough. Instead of guessing.

@Amarth because they almost never reply. The only reply I recall is from someone who was question banned and knew this wasn't the right place but asked anyway. 1 reply from hundreds of questions from various people asking why they have posted  here doesn't really allow one to draw much in the way of sensible conclusions.

Since that was deleted. I'd assure you that if we didn't delete them quickly, they'd overwhelm legitimate questions. On a mature network/site metas are generally quiet , this one included, unless someone gets up on a soapbox, or sets something on fire. 4-5 of these posts... adds up

Better options needs a little more engagement/understanding from the company than we have. People have tried asking the posters, people have suggested solutions, but this has been what has gotten us the best results. Whack a Mole might not be efficient or elegant, but sometimes, when its all you have at hand, you can hammer in a nail with a sufficiently large wrench. Gimme the TINIEST bit of friction and the problem would go alway

@RobertLongson In that case just close their questions and move on. If they have no interest in interacting then they are obviously not interested in getting answer either. There is no problem to solve here in that case.

"The problem is the physical layout." -- Could you, perhaps, write an answer detailing that hypothesis? I suppose it may be a different question, "why do they keep going" as opposed to "why do they end up in that situation where they may keep going". To me this is akin to people driving into a lake because SatNav said so, or an 18-wheeler going for 5 clicks through narrow forest road only to end up falling through a bridge... even though there were so many signs along the way telling the driver "you're in the wrong place".

Could it be related to this? If that's the culprit, I suppose users would have already made at least one post on a different site...

@CDR in typical cases I see an account created on the proper site, but no questions on it. Although it's entirely possible that these accounts all have one or more deleted questions, I suppose.

A case (likely to be deleted soon and thus only visible to users with more than 10,000 reputation points). It isn't for a newly created account (on Stack Overflow).

My own best guess is that many times the reasoning is the "Featured" links in the right sidebar.
They appear on each and every Stack Exchange site, and stand out.
So I believe that's a possible scenario:

User reach the proper site and browsing it a bit, intending to post a question there.
The user notice the Featured links, and finds one of them interesting.
The user clicks the link, and reach the post on Meta Stack Exchange.
The user read it, and doesn't notice it's actually on a different site.
The user is done reading, and proceed to ask their question.
Kaboom. Question posted here, and user has no idea it's wrong.

That's easy to handle in the UI level, as each link in the Featured box already has clear indicator that when visited, the user clicked the link, it's done by appending extra querystring parameter: cb=1. (Community Box flag.)
So it's possible to check for that flag in the question page, and when the flag is raised i.e. user arrived by clicking it in the box, show a very clear sign that it's Meta Stack Exchange, and possibly even detect what site the user reached from (e.g. using the referer header) and link back to it.

In a sense, its easier to find the wrong meta than the right site? :D

@JourneymanGeek it’s certainly hard to find the right site even via searching, IMO. If I use “search all sites” on the main StackExchange landing page, looking for “Astronomy”, all I get are results on other sites like StackOverflow. And the “All Sites” link doesn’t really help unless you also do a Ctrl-F on the page to look for a site. Idk if there’s a better way to find a site other than Google for it, but it’s certainly not intuitive. (In fact, there are results for Hinduism, Arqade, Statistics, and Code Review, among others, that come before the first result from Astronomy)

Also, in a sense the 'old' design is a lot more intuitive for finding things - Meta's right there. That said, Ironically, I think site discoverability is one of those things that needs an outsider's perspective. I know how things work - and our lost souls clearly don't.  I'd also suggest no one has any idea what the network front page should be like :D

I'm a big fan of Adam Savage's concept of first order retrievability, and I'd say meta is too easy to find on the front page. Ironically I've been complaining per site metas are too hard to find, and this is the sort of discoverability I would want
I'm not a UX person so feel free to tell me when I'm wrong.
Lets look at the top bar and a chunk of the front page

 note: A unregistered user won't see the filtered questions link.  
Its a pretty busy page. I've never been a fan of icons as links, and the set to the right don't tell a new user anything.
Unlike every other site/landing page you have direct links to essential help pages and meta on the top bar. Its literally the first page you'd see, and it follows almost the same pattern that the SE landing page. Its a list of questions, and it has an ask questions page.
Finding meta is too intuitive.
While I'd rather have aspects of the 'old' style SE page into our more modern site designs - I'd wonder if removing the meta link from the top bar would help. I see the value of quick access to the tour and about us for a new user first finding the network - Its in an obvious place to find, on the top drawer so to say. Instead of that perhaps move the "All Sites" link up as communities, or have something in the style of the digests page, that has a really good summary of what each site is to help people find a site - but isn't a mailing list sign up

I'd want someone to end up somewhere like here from the front page, not meta. A link, a short write up of whom the site is for. A search on top. Its not meant to point someone to the right site as designed but it seems like an elegant platform for that if someone finds it. It just needs a little refinement.
The top bar workflow I'd see is - "Find out how we work" "Find out who we are" "Find the right site for you" (rather than here's meta, go nuts).
