# Automatically raise the rep limit for posting to MSE to 2 when a meta post gets featured

Tags: feature-request, meta, privileges, featured-tag

I just noticed that there's a post tagged with [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) on Meta Stack Exchange when browsing Stack Overflow:

[image: One of the posts under the Featured On Meta section is a MSE post]

The last time this happened, [users from SO forgot that they're not on SO and asked programming questions that have nothing to do with Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278562/sudden-increase-in-off-topic-posts-on-mse). As a result, we raised the reputation requirement for asking and answering questions on MSE to 2 (i.e only the users who have the association bonus could use MSE), and it worked perfectly - there were literally no off-topic posts.

So, why not automate this process? If we bump the rep requirement for participating in MSE to 2 whenever a meta post gets [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) and bring it back to 1 when it's no longer [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) we can keep Meta clean with little to no effort.

Comment: "Last time this happened" it was an inbox notification. We've featured things in the sidebar many, many times in the past and it's never caused as many problems as that inbox notification did.

Answer (score 14):

The previous incident didn't happen because a meta post was featured.  Meta posts are featured all the time without that problem.  The problem arose from users getting an inbox notification which, when clicked, brought them to another site.  Since this isn't doing that, there's no real need for this.