# How do I view the posting guidelines and FAQ for a site?

Tags: support, help-center

How do I view the posting guidelines and FAQ for a site? I would like to post a question to one of the sites on the network, but am not sure it would be appropriate for the specific site I have in mind.

Comment: strongly related: [Ways to give users some specific education about question quality and topicality](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277607/165773) and [Usability issues for first-time Stack Exchange users - a micro-study](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279661/165773)

Answer (score 4):

Visit the on-topic page for that specific site, either by clicking on:

> Help --> Help Center --> What topics can I ask about here?

Or by simply accessing this link:

> http://**site**.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

If still in doubt after reading the on-topic page, go to the chat room or the meta site of that site and ask there.

Answer (score 2):

You can click on **help** (beside the search box) and take the two-minute tour (site address/tour, for example, meta.stackexchange.com/tour) or visit their Help Center (site address/help).

If you are still not sure about whether your question would be on-topic or not, you can post a question on the site's meta and get an answer from experienced users over there.