# Provide a summary of an SE site up-front

Tags: feature-request

I suggest providing a summary of the purpose of a StackExchange site up-front (i.e., near the top of the page).

Probably as a "Rounded/Squared Question Mark" button to the left of the site's logo, which upon click will pop up a box containing the site's description. Implemented this way, it won't become a clutter, and yet allow for a long-and-detailed description.

This feature will, IMO, help newcomers quickly find out what a certain SE Site is about.

(In fact, I'm not a newcomer (have been using SE for quite some time), yet when I landed on an SE Site I had to spelunk quite a bit to find out what exactly the site was about, to determine whether my question should be asked in that site or on another.)

---

***Edit:*** After reading [the question 'suggested' as duplicate of this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277607/ways-to-give-users-some-specific-education-about-question-quality-and-topicality) I have to disagree. *That* question was specifically about new user. But this question is about **a newcomer to an SE subsite, not necessarily a new SE user**.

As I have explained in my endnote of the original question, *I* am not a new SE user, yet when I happened on a subsite that I have never visited before, say [this one](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), I honestly have no idea what the site was about (i.e., what questions are welcome and what are not). And I have been a not-new-user for quite some time I forgot how to find info about the site.

I scroll dooooown, see "About Us", clicked... and off I went to a page about "The StackOverflow Company", not about the SE subsite. Only after clicking "Tour" did I find information to what a subsite is about. And that led me to a new page (or opens a new tab depending if I forgot to hold Ctrl or not).

Comment: you are eliminating 1 click of the current summary which is 2 clicks away, Help > Tour. there are also briefer summaries located [here](http://stackexchange.com/sites)

Comment: We already have the [Tour] which I think does a great job of leading new users into the [help/on-topic] for each site.

Comment: see also [Usability issues for first-time Stack Exchange users - a micro-study](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279661/usability-issues-for-first-time-stack-exchange-users-a-micro-study) (@PolyGeo tl;dr of this study is, Tour sucks in helping site newcomers)

Comment: @Memor-X yeah, sorry that I _cannot memorize all URLs related to Stack Exchange_. So I went there and... a bunch of icons. Oh, I have to click to make it a list and... ahh, a list of icons with _short_ descriptions. Go there and joined and asked a question and... got told that "Hey you shouldn't ask that here but there or there"...

Comment: @PolyGeo the problem with the word "Tour" is that it assumes the user is totally new to SE. What about users, like me, who are _not_ new to SE... just wanting to know what a subsite is _exactly_ about before asking a new question? (Plus, the connotation of the word "Tour" -- guide for total newbies. That's why I don't click on that the first time, until I became desperate.)

Answer (score 6):

You're right; newcomers to a site should see a short summary of what the site is about.  Fortunately, they do: if you visit a site where you don't yet have an account, you see something like this:

[image: summary and invitation]

In addition, there's the "tour" link in the top bar, right next to "join this community".

Comment: Sometimes the single sentence is not specific enough. Resulting in wasted time as I ask a question that someone then say "Hey, you shouldn't ask that here... go to so and so instead." Then I have to re-ask the question _there_. Plus the downvotes.

Comment: That text is the description, which is what you asked for.  it's the same description that appears on the list of all sites.  If what you meant is that you want an *expanded* description -- a paragraph or two instead of a phrase or sentence -- then, first off, people would have to write those, and then you'd need to figure out where to display them.  That's a different question than the one I answered.