# Can a declined flag be reverted or removed from history?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

I've received a "declined" response on a tag, which actually was helpful as confirmed by <insert some authoritative but obscure link to SO, like some tag page that tells that this tag became off-topic at some time>. I've filled another flag with explanation and it was deemed "helpful". Can a moderator remove wrong "declined" status from my previous flag?

Comment: This question seems to be popular, but I couldn't find direct answer to it except in comments to related answers on declined flags questions, so I think it must be formulated somewhere, so people just stop asking it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, a moderator can't revert it; all decisions are permanent. It works this way to save moderators' time and not to introduce additional workload on moderators associated with "flag/decline/appeal/decline/appeal/..." chain that will inevitably caused by ability to appeal flags.

Comment: When we decline a flag, it's generally because we didn't see anything actionable from the flag and the flag was unhelpful to us. It doesn't necessarily mean our decision was either right or wrong. However if you flag again with explanation, and that explanation is justified then we'll gladly act on it, thereby marking it as helpful.

Comment: In this particular case I've started to seen answer for "can be reverted?" question after I've got "declined" on off-topic flag that I've placed on code golf question and as it's tag page say, it is off-topic indeed. This is irrelevant to this MSO question however, I just wanted to have one clear "no, can't be done, forget it" somewhere without fishing it in comments.

Comment: I guess it also depends on the individual moderator - not all of us will agree on a single decision sometimes.

Comment: Or first moderator simply could be a new one who wasn't aware about golf at the moment. Still, I have nothing against this process, just want to provide clear statement in this Q&A about how it works.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, flag removal once happened at at Super User, per their meta discussion:

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JQ86.jpg]

Per my reading, at SU flags were removed not by moderator, but by a developer.

---

Some time ago I also reported about my flags being removed, but I have neither screen shots to prove that flags were there, nor confirmation from developer / moderator that there was a removal:

- [My "not an answer" flag is gone and not showing in my history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110016/my-not-an-answer-flag-is-gone-and-not-showing-in-my-history)

Comment: What a story! But the flow really looks like exception from the rule because of how extreme it declining was.