# If I flag a question as offtopic, it's declined and then moved can I get rid of the unhelpful flag?

Tags: support, flags, declined-flags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can a declined flag be reverted or removed from history?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136876/can-a-declined-flag-be-reverted-or-removed-from-history)

A while ago I [flagged a question](https://serverfault.com/questions/335135/dhcp-address-leases-to-sql-server-database) up as off-topic on stack-overflow. At the time of the flag, the question got moved, however the flag I suggested (off-topic, suggested move to server-fault) was rejected as unhelpful... even though the question was moved. I suspect just a miss-click.

Is there any way to ask for someone to re-look at it or am I just stuck with the 1 unhelpful flag. I realise this is very very unimportant in the grand scheme of things, just a bad case of OCD kicking in here.

Comment: You're stuck. Decisions on flags are irreversible.

Comment: I assumed as much :) but always worth a shot in asking anyway.

Comment: Yeah, almost everything else can be reversed.

Comment: [Can a declined flag be reverted or removed from history?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136876/can-a-declined-flag-be-reverted-or-removed-from-history)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your flag was probably declined because of how painfully short and poorly-researched the question was... as mods, we usually refrain from migrating poor questions (note that one of the diamond mods who voted to close that question wasn't yet with us at that time, hence the non-binding close vote, and he may very well have chosen "off topic" instead of "belongs on Server Fault").

There's nothing you can do about this, I'm afraid.